# Recreating c# method in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am converting methods from my C# selenium framework into a Java equivalent
All is good except a particular method shown below

```
    public class BusinessUserDetails
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string BusinessId { get; set; }
    }

    public static BusinessUserDetails JoinExistingSmeInitialize(string email = null)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var randNumber = rand.Next(1, 9999999);
        email = email ?? "auto-test_" + randNumber + "@mailinator.com";
        return new BusinessUserDetails
        {
            Email = email,
        };
```

Im converting it to Java and have got this far

```
public class BusinessUserDetails
{
    private String Email;
    public final String getEmail()
    {
        return Email;
    }
    public final String setEmail(String value)
    {
        Email = value;
        return value;
    }

    private String BusinessId;
    public final String getBusinessId()
    {
        return BusinessId;
    }
    public final void setBusinessId(String value)
    {
        BusinessId = value;
    }

}

    public BusinessUserDetails JoinExistingSmeInitialize(String email) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNumber = rand.nextInt(9999999);
    email = (email != null) ? email : "auto-test_" + randNumber + "@mailinator.com";

    }
```

The one i cant seem to convert is this

```
        return new BusinessUserDetails
    {
        Email = email,
    };
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In Java we use [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a constructor in your `BusinessUserDetails` to set the `Email` field. Then use :

```
return new BusinessUserDetails(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have that kind of constructor initialization. You need to create a constructor that takes a `String` as a param:-

```
public BusinessUserDetails(String email) {
    Email = email;
}
```

and then the code you can't get to work would just be:-

```
return new BusinessUserDetails(email);
```

I would also recommend using Java coding conventions, especially not using a capital letter for instance names, as it will make understanding your code a lot easier.

Comment: Thansk for the above but i prob need to add some extra info

Comment: You can add them as params to the Constructor.